# WPF - using IsInitialized as Property Trigger fails

Tags: wpf, properties, triggers

The object is an ListBoxItem, although I tried with a Panel as well.

I get this error message: `Property can not be null on Trigger.`, within an InvalidOperationException.

Here's the trigger:

```
<Trigger Property="IsInitialized" Value="true">
    <Setter TargetName="MyPanel" Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue">
    </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

**Note:** I can't use `Loaded`, because I don't want it to fire whenever the control is rendered. Just at initializiation.

This property exists... why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `IsInitialized` property is not a [Dependency Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx). Triggers can only be used with dependency properties.

But the question is why would you need such a trigger? Because the same effect can be achieved just by specifying the `Background` property directly on `MyPanel` or in the style of `ListBoxItem'.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Actually, I think my question should be another... I wonder if I'll need to open another question... I have an ObservableCollection and a ListBox binded to it. I set a trigger to IsSelected, so if I select an item, it becomes blue. Something funny happens, though, when I change an item directly (as in List[1] = something). It keeps selected even when I click other items. Why is that?

Comment: @Conrad - You are welcome :) As for your second question, you better create another post for that and I will try to look into it.